# How to custom title of BrowseFragment by layout

Tags: android, android-tv, smart-tv

I just started with Android Smart TV and was recommended by Google to use BrowseFragment to display the content list.
The problem here is that I want to replace the Row's Text Tittle with another layout (in this case is ImageView)
How can I do that:
[image]

Comment: Do you mean every *list rows* title ?

Comment: Yes!, I want add image AbemaTV to list rows title

Comment: You mean only this *image AbemaTV text* or it have image also ?

Comment: The each Row have one Title and it alway is textview, I just wanna replace to ImageView like picture above (AbemaTV is imageView)

Comment: I think you might need to customize *HeaderItem* to achieve that.